# Changing Docked Scrollbar Spacing/Margin

Tags: c#, winforms, scrollbar

For the current custom winforms control that I am writing, I need to dock my own horizontal and vertical scroll bars. I have a slight issue with the spacing of the controls at the bottom right corner though. Here is a picture of the problem:

[image]

And here is what I want to see:

[image]

Notice the gap between the controls? Both horizontal and vertical scroll bars are docked to the panel, one to the bottom, and one to the right. I tried setting the margin, but it seems to have no effect at all. I will also state that I cannot use a prebuilt-scrollpanel, because I am using an OpenTK GLControl as the primary widget/control. I need my own dedicated scrollbars. I am also NOT using the Visual Studio form-builder.

Some Pseudo code, which should not need to be expressed, but here it is anyway.

```
{
        HorizontalScrollBar = new HScrollBar();
        HorizontalScrollBar.Margin = new Padding(0, 0, 31, 0);
        HorizontalScrollBar.Dock = DockStyle.Bottom;
        VerticalScrollBar = new VScrollBar();
        VerticalScrollBar.Margin = new Padding(0, 0, 0, 31);
        VerticalScrollBar.Dock = DockStyle.Right;
}
```

**----------
| Update |
----------**

Using the suggestion given by the user @Loathing, I came up with this solution:

```
        protected override void OnSizeChanged(EventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnSizeChanged(e);
            this.HorizontalScrollBar.MaximumSize = new Size(
                this.ClientSize.Width - 16,
                Int32.MaxValue);
            this.VerticalScrollBar.MaximumSize = new Size(
                Int32.MaxValue,
                this.ClientSize.Height - 16);
        }
```

And here is a picture of what it looks like now:

[image]

Comment: The height / width of the scrollbars will depend on the DPI of the computer. So it is better to use the `SystemInformation` class rather than hardcoded values.

Comment: @Loathing Good to know, thanks.

Comment: @Loathing This does not seem to work for the vertical scroll bar position, though. It appear against the bottom right hand corner again. Any ideas?

Comment: @Loathing Wait nevermind, I fixed it. I didnt need to minus by an offset of 16.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could set the maximum width when the parent size changes, or you could write a custom layout engine.

```
protected override void OnSizeChanged(EventArgs e) {
    base.OnSizeChanged(e);
    hbar.MaximumSize = new System.Drawing.Size(this.ClientSize.Width - SystemInformation.VerticalScrollBarWidth, int.MaxValue);
}
```

Comment: This worked; I have updated my original post with the final snippet of code based upon your suggestion. Thank you.